# Buildr JVM properties for JUnit set inside the JVM rather than outside

Tags: properties, junit, jvm, buildr

When using JUnit we pass the directory used for logging as a JVM property. This works fine on the command line and in Eclipse. However, it doesn't work when we pass the same property to the Buildr test task.

```
test.using :properties => { :"server.name" => "tester", :"log.dir" => log_dir}
```

We know why this happening. The property is being set from inside the JVM rather than outside. This means that at run time (when the static logging class is loaded) the property is not yet set. If we query the property later (say from within a unit test) then we see that it is set correctly.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

BTW, we're using log4J but the question is applicable to any static class that needs access to a JVM property set by Buildr.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using JUnit, you can ensure that the tests run in a forked JVM via

```
test.using :fork => :once
```

However I thought that was the default behaviour? Are you overriding this somehow? (See  http://buildr.apache.org/languages.html)

Comment: Yes Peter, we already tried using all the fork options, to no avail. We've had similar problems before calling Java from Ruby. It appears that Ruby creates the JVM first and sets the properties a fraction later. But this is enough to screw-up static classes that need to read JVM properties. The most obvious solution is to create our own buildr tasks which simply calls a shell script to execute the tests, but I want to see if there is a solution within buildr before going down that route.

Answer (score 0):

this [code](https://github.com/tofferoma/l4j-buildr-properties) defines the log.dir in the log4j.properties file and sets it in the buildfile via

```
test.using :properties => { :"log.dir" => '/tmp'}
```

my setup is

- buildr 1.4.7
- ruby 1.9.3

hth